# Cannot create a build archive in Flutter

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter

When creating a build archive in Xcode, get these error messages. But I can run the app in my iOS device.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in libfirebase_admob.a(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
      -[LocationPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in liblocation.a(LocationPlugin.o)
      ___52+[FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:]_block_invoke in libshared_preferences.a(SharedPreferencesPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_admob.a(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_admob.a(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in liblocation.a(LocationPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in libshared_preferences.a(SharedPreferencesPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterEventChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in liblocation.a(LocationPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: is there any update on this?, could you run the app? i have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing armv7 support in your Flutter.framework.That's why you could run on your arm64 device but failed to archive for generic devices. Follow these instructions to produce a Flutter.framework that supports armv7. [Armv7 build instructions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine). And take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2089) might help.